# Compatibility mysql 5.6 and 5.7

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, mysql-5.7

I have mysql 5.7 on my computer.
External library uses "SET storage_engine=INNODB;" in their sources.
I need to use this option.
This option was disabled in 5.7.5 version.

How to enable "Compatibility Mode" with old version mysql?

Answer (score 0):

There is no compatibility mode for that variable.

You must use `SET GLOBAL default_storage_engine=InnoDB` now.

If you can't change the library that sets that variable, you'll have to downgrade to MySQL 5.6 until the library can be changed.

You can't say there was no warning! The `storage_engine` variable has been deprecated since MySQL 5.5.3, 2010-07-06

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_storage_engine